# My grammar doesn't work as required in antlr

Tags: antlr

I have written a grammar in antlr as follows:

```
grammar names;
init : stat+;
stat : name NEWLINE
     | name SPACE NEWLINE
     |NEWLINE
     | name SPACE name SPACE
     ;
name : ID ;
ID : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ; 
SPACE : ' ';
```

this grammar should accept input of form :

```
name1
name1<space>name2<space>
name1<space>
```

I am not getting the required output. As of now the generated tree shows only the first value. I am a novice to antlr and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stat rule should be more like this:

```
stat: name (SPACE name)* SPACE? NEWLINE;
```

assuming from you small example that each line represents a complete entry matched by the stat rule.